# How do I separate my text box from the label?

Tags: html, css, forms

What I would like is to have a column of labels, and to the right a column of text boxes approximately a few tabs apart and all aligned on (their respective) margins.

So far I have this. However when I resize the screen my text boxes move. How can I make them fixed?

This is the CSS:

```
#layout {
    background-color: #f5fffa;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#zero {
    text-align: center;
}

#one {
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    border:4px solid #18ab29;
    border-width: 4px;
    background-color: #44c767;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-left: 9em;
    padding-right: 9em;
}

.myform {
    width:40px;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    right: 800px;
    height: 1.5em;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="layout">

<h1 id="zero">Title</h1>

    <form id="one">
    <br>
        <label>input one:</label>
        <input type="text" class="myform" value="0" /><br><br>
        <label>input two:</label>
        <input type="text" class="myform" value="0" /></br>
    </br>
    </form>

</div>
```

EDIT:

I've figured it out:

Add this:

```
#one label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 270px;
}
```

And take away:

position: absolute;
right: 800px;

from 
    .myform {
        width:40px;
        text-align: left;
        position: absolute;
        right: 800px;
        height: 1.5em;
    }

Answer (score 0):

try to give the `label` a width:

```
label {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#layout {
  background-color: #f5fffa;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#zero {
  text-align: center;
}
#one {
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 4px solid #18ab29;
  border-width: 4px;
  background-color: #44c767;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 1.5em;
}
.myform {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  right: 800px;
}
.leftCol {
  float: left;
  width: 50%
}
.rightCol {
  float: right;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div id="layout">

  <h1 id="zero">Title</h1>

  <form id="one">
    <div class="leftCol">
      <label>input one:</label>
      <input type="text" value="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="rightCol">
      <label>input two:</label>
      <input type="text" value="0" />
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `position:absolute` from the inputs (because in my screen they where way of, that's why you should use it if nothing else works) and then added a `margin-right` on the form labels. [**demo;**](http://jsfiddle.net/gs2b0jua/)

### Relevant CSS

```
#one label{
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

### Update

I've added a fixed width to ammend for the possibility of labels with differente text lengths, here it is:

```
#one label{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:150px;
}
```

You should change `width:150px` to whatever you want it to be :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: It almost does! unfortunately though when the length of the labels are different, the text boxes are not aligned. thanks anyway

Comment: Glad I could help, remember to click the green tick next to the answer if you feel like I've solved your problem :)